# How to extract a number from a string using Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

How would I extract the number 2,550 from the string "2,550 Things" using Puppeteer?

```
<div id="container" role="main">
  <h3 class="highlightedText" role="heading">2,550 Things</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```js
await page.waitForSelector('div#container > h3.highlightedText');
const text = await page.$eval(
    'div#container > h3.highlightedText',
    el => el.innerText.replace(/\s+.*/, "")
);
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I am looking for.